# Add new remote and every pull creates new merge commit

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have a project that was hooked up to a gitlab repository for its remote. That gitlab has become unusable for one reason or another and I want to move over to github. So I cloned the repository and pushed it to github, getting rid of all the branch history in the process. This was on purpose since this project is now being maintained again after ~4 inactive years and we want to start fresh. The branches will be saved in the gitlab history for the time being.

The problem is I want to keep the gitlab remote for a time. I added the github remote and pull from that remote when changes are made, but every single time it tells me that I need to do a merge commit, which is cluttering up the commit history. I am not making any local changes in between pulls, so what is causing this? Does it have to do with the branches? Or is it a product of having two remotes? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a result of having two remotes.  However, it probably is a result of trying to have two histories for the same branch.  You can't do that.

So you have your original repo.  And that might look something like

```
... x -- x -- O <--(master)
     \
       x ... <--(some_branch)
```

Now you say you want a fresh start, so I assume that means your new repo will just have the one commit matching the content at `O`.  Note that I didn't say "the same commit', but rather a "commit matching the content".  That's because changing the history requires creating a new commit.[1]

Now, you didn't specify *how* you created the new repo, but almost every way of doing it would end up with something like this

```
O' <--(github/master)

... x -- x -- O <--(gitlab/master)
     \
       x ... <--(gitlab/some_branch)
```

(where gitlab and github would be replaced with whatever remote names you used).  You can verify that with something like

```
git show gitlab/master
git show github/master
```

and note that the commits' SHA identifiers (the strings of 40 numbers and letters) are almost certainly different.

And the question is, when you try to pull from one of these remote branches, what is checked out locally?  If `master` points to `O` (i.e. tracks `gitlab/master`) and you pull `github/master`, then this would require a merge across unrelated histories - which you definitely don't want to do.

So if you want two remotes with different histories, then a single remote that links to both of them will need to maintain a separate set of local branches corresponding to each of those histories.  And that means that changes applied to one history will not easily migrate to the other.  Of course if all changes are going to the new repo, that might be ok.  You could, once you have at least one new commit in github, use something like `git replace` in the local repo to make everything appear locally as one unified history.

So for example, you could do something like this

```
git checkout github/master
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master -t github/master
git checkout gitlab/master
git branch old/master
# maybe do similar renamings for other old branches
```

Then when you have `master` checked out you can push and pull (to github) as normal.  You wouldn't really want to push or pull from gitlab - it's just there for reference, right?  So then the only question is whether you want to locally make it easier to interact with the older history.  As noted above, I think you'd really want to wait until you had some new commits in the github repo.  But then once you have

```
O' -- A <--(master)(github/master)

... x -- x -- O <--(refs/heads/old/master)(gitlab/master)
     \
       x ... <--(gitlab/some_branch)
```

(note that I spelled out the full ref name of old/master to avoid confusing it with the remote ref names)...

At this point on a local basis you could use `git replace` to substitute `O` for `O'`.

```
git replace master^ gitlab/master
```

(where `master^` is some expression that resolves to `O'` - in this example `master^` works because `master` points to `A`, whose parent is `O'`.)

There are some quirks with git replace so I recommend reviewing the documentation if you're thinking of using it.  (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-replace)

This way of combining histories is purely smoke and mirrors and would have to be set up in each local repo that wants it; so if you anticipate doing that going forward, you should put a tag at `O'` so it's easy to refer to it later.

---

[1] I am assuming here that you're not trying to use shallow histories.  If that assumption is wrong correct me and I"ll update accordingly.

For now I'll just say: Creating a shallow clone of gitlab and using that to populate github seems at first like an attractive option for your use case, specifically because it allows sharing the `O` commit and using it as a link between the repos' histories.  But I believe there would be a significant risk of accidentally pushing the full history into the shallow repo - especially if you keep any locals that contain the full history and use both remotes.

Comment: This is great and exactly what I'm looking for, I think. The gitlab is just there for reference and I don't care if it's easier to interact with the gitlab history locally. So I think the code block with all the checkout and branches is what I'm looking for, but could you perhaps insert some comments on what is going on in there? If I understand correctly it's something like: move to github master, delete the local master, recreate local master and attach it to github master. Then go to the gitlab master and rename it to old. Is that necessary or after recreating master I can use it normally?

Comment: That's basically right.  You can skip creating `_old` branches if you don't want them

Answer (score 1):

I would do this with cherry-pick.

This is how you copy a commit from github to gitlab:

Pull both remotes to one repo, into 2 different branches(let's say `ghB` for GitHub and `glB` for GitLab and `ghR` for the GitHub remote and `glR` for the GitLab remote)

Setup:

```
git init
git remote add glR <gitlab url>
git remote add ghR <github url>
git pull glR glB
git pull ghR ghB
```

Get the commit hash of the github-commit:

```
git checkout ghB
git log
```

Checkout the gitlab branch

```
git checkout glB
```

Cherry-pick(copy) the commit of the github branch

```
git cherry-pick <commit hash>
```

Push it

```
git push -u glR glB
```